# Trying to use clock_t but compiler gods hate me

Tags: c

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with my code. The compiler keeps getting implicit declaration of function

```
'clock'[ -Wimpliciit-fucntion-declaration] clock_t start = clock();
```

and

```
'CLOCKS_PER_SEC' undeclared
```

The code which leads to these errors is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define N_TIMES     600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE   10000


int main(void)
{
    double  *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double  sum = 0;
    int     i;

    int j;
    clock_t start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j +=4){
            sum += array[j];
            sum += array[j + 1];
            sum += array[j + 2];
            sum += array[j + 3];
        }
    }

    printf ("%.1f seconds\n", (double) (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been reading all the related posts and the GNU library but can't figure out the issue.

Comment: `#include <time.h>`

Comment: Thank you for time and help

Answer (score 1):

[`clock` is defined in `<time.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock), as is [`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/CLOCKS_PER_SEC).

You need to include that header.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. By the way Donatello is by far the more superior turtle

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `#include` the required header file for [`clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock). Add

```
#include <time.h>
```

to the file.

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is also `#define`d in the same file.